# How to fetch value from property file when my key is a dynamic in mule?

Tags: error-handling, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am trying to fetch value from the properties file

```
"mykey" = "value"
"mykey1" ="value2"
```

in mule, we can fetch the value by ${mykey}, but what if mykey is stored in a variable named keyName.
I tried fetching the value by writing ${(#vars.keyName)} . But it is not working

Comment: My understanding is you have a property file on your classpath in your mule project. You want to use the property value inside the dataweave script . Right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use #[p(vars.keyName)] to retrieve value for key stored in variable keyName from a property file.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Mule::p`, just `p` could get deprecated in the future.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var myPropName = "test"
---
Mule::p(myPropName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *p* function:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-mule-functions-p

```
p('mykey')
```